# Which C-standard introduced the "__weak" keyword?

Tags: c

I would like to use `__weak` in a library I am creating, but I want to make sure it is compliant with a known "C-number" standard. Which standard introduced this? Or is it a non-standard compiler extension that most compilers have supported? (Either through the keyword or `__attribute__`.)

EDIT: Probably should not have used the term "keyword", mostly interested if "weak" in some form is a standard?

Comment: `__weak` is not part of the C standard.

Comment: [None](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword). It's not a standard language keyword, and never has been.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- Is the idea of `weak` in any C-standard with implementation left up to the compiler writer?

Comment: @PeterT: Everything not in the C standard is left up to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__weak` is not part of the C standard.

`__weak` is a compiler extension specific to the compiler, for example available on Keil and COSMIC compiler. `__attribute__` is a compiler extensions from gcc GNU C compiler, available for example on clang, TASKING Compiler, TI Arm Compiler, and so on. For example, `__weak` is invalid on gcc.

You can browse [STM32CubeF4/cmsis_compiler.h](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/blob/2f3b26f16559f7af495727a98253067a31182cfc/Drivers/CMSIS/Core_A/Include/cmsis_compiler.h#L33) for some compiler-specific macros definitions for STM32Cube project for *some* compilers.

It is common, because of the popularity of [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), which has the support for weak symbols.